# How to script a table?

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-2014, scripting

When I right-click a table in Object Explorer and click "Script Table" I can get SSMS to script my table.

Can I do that with T-SQL code?

I'm after the "CREATE TABLE xx" code that SSMS generates, so that I can take the script and use on other projects. I need all the bits and pieces, including PRIMARY KEY, CONSTRAINTs, "WITH (PAD_INDEX = " and schema declaration.

I'm on SQL Server 2014

Comment: Can you please  be more specific by what you mean by "T-sql code"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 2012 onwards this is possible and can be done with help OF `sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set` DMV.

> This dynamic management function takes a Transact-SQL statement as a
>   parameter and describes the metadata of the first result set for the
>   statement

You can refer here for a read on this [sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878258.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Also, refer to this post explaining the same. [Is there a way to generate table create script in TSQL?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53085/is-there-a-way-to-generate-table-create-script-in-tsql)