# how do I duplicate a partitioned table in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, partitioning

I have a database with several tables that are heavily partitioned and I'm trying to optimize part of an ETL operation that involves one of those tables. The table has 1347 partitions involving 35 different file groups. I want to recreate the table in a different database but I don't see a way to get the partition scheme definition or function definition for my new database (it's not included when I script the table out in SSMS). I can get other pieces of the puzzle with the query below but I can't seem to find a way to bring it all together! I've created the new database with all the filegroups and such to match the original.

```
select distinct 
ps.Name AS PartitionScheme, pf.name AS PartitionFunction,fg.name AS FileGroupName, rv.value AS PartitionFunctionValue
    from sys.indexes i  
    join sys.partitions p ON i.object_id=p.object_id AND i.index_id=p.index_id  
    join sys.partition_schemes ps on ps.data_space_id = i.data_space_id  
    join sys.partition_functions pf on pf.function_id = ps.function_id  
    left join sys.partition_range_values rv on rv.function_id = pf.function_id AND rv.boundary_id = p.partition_number
    join sys.allocation_units au  ON au.container_id = p.hobt_id   
    join sys.filegroups fg  ON fg.data_space_id = au.data_space_id  
where i.object_id = object_id('PartitionedTable')
```

The database is on SQL Server 2016 SP1 CU7 Enterprise Edition

Comment: Did you look at this? [how to generate the creation script for partition function and partition schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/171365/how-to-generate-the-creation-script-for-partition-function-and-partition-schema)

Comment: @SqlWorldWide I hadn't seen that and it provided me exactly what I needed!